# The package 'mongodb' is not recognized after installing it using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, npm

I have install mongodb using NodeJS using this command `npm i mongodb -g`
and when i call it in the CMD its give an error that is not recognized the command.

what could it be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `npm install mongodb` that is the *driver* for NodeJS to run MongoDB. You still need to install mongodb itself. Instructions for that can be found here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/installation/

Comment: That's wired that you would need a local mongodb installed on you'r machine. the C# mongo driver for example can be used as an interface to any mongo instance.